# How to choose best estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

I have two estimators $T_1$ and $T_2$. $T_1$ is better than $T_2$ based on MSE. But $T_2$ is Pitman closer than $T_1.$ The question is which of these estimators can be useful?

Answer (score 0):

I have also came acrross this problem before. My advisor stated that "$T_{1}$ is more reasonable than $T_{2}$". 
see the following paper. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290692?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents